# subversion client for ruby?

Tags: ruby, svn, version-control

is there are proper subversion client for ruby, that could be used to manage text files, images and other documents from a subversion project? it needs to be able to checkout the project, update and merge content (not automatically, but respond with a diff or something in case of a problem), commit, etc.

please don't ask me how we got there ;) but our cms is actually just an svn project (including text files which include html, images and other documents) and we'd like to build some kind of frontend in ruby where people can edit the text files, upload new documents, etc.

so we would need all these svn features and we would like to have them abstracted in some kind of way so we don't have to use bash commands interacting with the svn client installation.

Comment: the bindings for ruby have moved to
http://alagazam.net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are [subversion bindings for Ruby](http://warehouseapp.com/installing/ruby-subversion-bindings) you could use if you want to roll your own in Ruby.  There is also [Apache mod_dav_svn](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re58.html), which is an already-existing application for subversion management (if you use Apache).

Answer (score 9):

You've probably found a working solution by now but thought I would share this anyway as I wrote a gem which may be useful.

http://rubygems.org/gems/svn_wc - svn_wc provides programmatic access to basic svn functions, utilizing the Subversion Ruby Bindings, exposing their functionality in a simplified way
source: http://github.com/dvwright/svn_wc

http://rubygems.org/gems/svn_wc_tree - svn_wc_tree provides an Web Application Front End GUI to a working copy of an remote SVN Repository. (rough and in progress)

Answer (score 1):

There are ruby binding for subversion (article here: http://alistairisrael.wordpress.com/2007/09/19/using-the-subversion-ruby-bindings/) available from gems.  What might be a useful exercise would be to take an existing CMS's gui and replace the datalayer with a ruby based one which maps the commands into subversion commands.